# Alternative to !is.na()?

Tags: r, data-analysis

What is the alternative of this statement below ?

```
not_cancelled <- flights %>% filter( !is.na(dep_delay), !is.na(arr_delay))
```

In this statement `!is.na(dep_delay)` is written. Is there any other way we could write it ?

Maybe like this `(dep_delay != NA)` ?

I tried writing it this way but it is not working.

Comment: what's wrong with `!is.na`

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/5686/69374

Comment: i just wanted to know if there is any alternative as well or not. @MichaelChirico

Comment: `dep_delay != NA` will not work unless your `NA`s are characters. You can replace `NA`s to 0 and then use `dep_delay != 0` but you are adding an unnecessary extra step in the process

Comment: It's so cumbersome to write !is.na. Hopefully, R can find something easier to write, e.g. not_na

Answer (score 1):

```
`%is%` <- function(x, y){
  if(is.na(y))
    return(is.na(x))
  if(x==y) return(TRUE)
  if(x!=y) return(FALSE)

}

c("A",2, NA) %is% NA
```

Try define the function like this.

Comment: You might return `x==y` instead of the two return

Comment: Fails with `1:3 %is% 2` or even `1:3 %is% 4`. It's no longer vectorized.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `!is.na` , we could use `is.finite`

```
x <- c(NA, 1:3)
!is.na(x)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

is.finite(x)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

However as @Roland pointed out they are not completely equivalent, they differ in the way they handle `Inf` values.

```
!is.na(Inf)
#[1] TRUE
is.finite(Inf)
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: That's not equivalent. is.finite also takes NaN and Inf into account.

Comment: I think they handle `NaN` in the similar fashion but yes, you are right about `Inf`.